# Including post id in url

Tags: php, wordpress

In one of my page templates for events there is a button that, when clicked, redirects that user to a form and carries over the information they filled out on the previous page. The action that creates the url structure for the redirect is:

`action="<?php echo site_url('/booking/'); ?>"`

How do I change this so that the post id for the event is included at the end of the url? eg www.mywebsite/booking/1234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're in The Loop, you can just [get the post ID](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID):

```
action="<?php echo site_url( '/booking/' . get_the_ID() ); ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
action="<?php echo site_url('/booking/'); ?>/?id=yourid"
```